# SSH and FoxyProxy - bringing a browser session from B to A via X

Tags: browser, ssh-tunnel

I shall try and be brief. English is my second language, so please forgive the lack of syntactic fluency.

I have done lots of researches but could not find a suitable article (perhaps because I am not using the appropriate search string). I would love an easy ready-made solution, however I am also keen on learning this stuff so I would be happy if someone could at least provide me a pointer.

I'll divide this into two categories: what I am currently doing and what I would like to do but have failed.

Two boxes running Ubuntu 10.04 - **Box A** (SSH client, Firefox, FoxyProxy) **-->** **Box B** (Running a security application - Apache port 8080)
In order to bring the security app that is running on Box B to my Box A, I connect from A to B in those steps:
Step 1: 
Command:

```
ssh -D 1080 <user>@<Box_B_IP>
```

Step 2:
I would launch my local Firefox (running under **Box A**'s) and, having FoxyProxy installed and configured to listen on **port 1080**, I make this my default proxy.

Step 3:
I then simply type the server IP on my local browser (**Box A**'s) specifying the port the application is listening on: **8080**

```
https://<Box_B_IP>:8080
```

This enables me to run the security application running under **Box B** as if it were sitting on my own client (**Box A**). This is all great except for the fact that my **Box B** is open to the world (OK there are iptables and firewalls, but that's beyond the point).

Thus, what I would like to do is to have a third box on the game, a 'jump' box in between **Boxes A** and **B** (call it **Box X**), so I can configure the iptables in **Box B** to only accept traffic coming from **Box X**, like this:
**A --> X --> B**

My assumption is that from **Box A** I should SSH to **Box X** using a certain parameter to then SSH into **Box B** using another parameter to bind the ports and be able to run the security application that runs in **B** to **A** via **X**.

I tried all combinations of parameters like `-D` and `-L` and port bindings that my dumb brain could think of.

How can I achieve this? Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is :

1. Start `ssh -D <local_port> <serverX>`
2. Configure your FoxyProxy (firefox) to use a socks5 proxy listening at `localhost` on port `<local_port>`
3. Navigate to your usual `<serverB>` address, with the proxy active.

And voilà !

I'm still looking for an automated way to start the local proxy when I access a specific subdomain.

Comment: Thanks ever so much for the suggestion. I just read it and am on the move so can't test right now. But will definitely try it out and post another comment with the result.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your scenario, you can use [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) to create a more secure connection to your web application running on Box B via Box A and a 'jump' Box X. Below are the steps:

1. **Isolate your web application:** Run your security application on Box B and take note of the ports it runs on. To secure it from unwanted access, use a firewall to block access to those ports on Box B.
2. **Generate Certificates:** You can generate localhost certificates for your application on Box B using the command: `mkcert localhost`.
3. **Set Up Port Forwarding:** Use SSH to create a secure tunnel from Box A to Box B via Box X with port forwarding. The command would be: `ssh -L local_port:Box_X:remote_port user@Box_X`. Here, `local_port` is a port on Box A, `Box_X` is your 'jump' box, `remote_port` is the port on Box B where your application runs, and `user` is your username on Box X. This command should be run from Box A.
4. **Access the Application:** Now, you can access your isolated and secure web application from Box A using the address: `https://localhost:local_port`.

This method allows you to run your security application on Box B in a more isolated and secure manner, accessible only from Box A via Box X. mkcert is instrumental in simplifying the process of generating localhost certificates.

This is just a high-level overview. The specifics can change based on your actual system configurations. If you need further assistance with any of these steps, don't hesitate to ask! I've also made a [helpful guide to using SSH tunneling with mkcert to run an actual remote browser application here](https://blog.dosyago.com/tutorials/2023/06/17/tunneling-browserbox-pro-over-SSH-complete-guide-to-using-port-forwarding-to-run-RBI-on-a-router.html), which may be more illustrative of your specific use case.